# Error in a C code which is translated from Fortran using a f2c

Tags: c, fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I have never coded in Fortran. So I have some work related to Fortran in which I converted that code to C. But when I am running the C code it is giving me the following error :

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccNX2LeT.o: In function `MAIN__':
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `f_open'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x2ca): undefined reference to `sqrt'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x400): undefined reference to `sqrt'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x487): undefined reference to `sqrt'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x6f1): undefined reference to `atan2'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x71b): undefined reference to `atan2'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x777): undefined reference to `sqrt'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x795): undefined reference to `cos'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x7bb): undefined reference to `sin'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x8ef): undefined reference to `s_wsle'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x908): undefined reference to `do_lio'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x921): undefined reference to `do_lio'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x93a): undefined reference to `do_lio'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x953): undefined reference to `do_lio'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x96c): undefined reference to `do_lio'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x974): undefined reference to `e_wsle'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x9b5): undefined reference to `s_wsle'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x9ce): undefined reference to `do_lio'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0x9fc): undefined reference to `do_lio'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0xa2e): undefined reference to `do_lio'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0xa60): undefined reference to `do_lio'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0xa92): undefined reference to `do_lio'
sinai_static.c:(.text+0xa9a): undefined reference to `e_wsle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The old Fortran code uses an external method from ran0.f. I think the problem is with opening a file as the translated code is using f_open(&o_1) which is giving an error. But I don't know how to resolve it.
I am attaching the C code for reference.

```
    #include "f2c.h"

/* Table of constant values */

static integer c__3 = 3;
static integer c__1 = 1;
static integer c__5 = 5;

/* Main program */ int MAIN__(void)
{
    /* System generated locals */
    integer i__1;
doublereal d__1, d__2, d__3, d__4;
olist o__1;

/* Builtin functions */
integer f_open(olist *);
double sqrt(doublereal), atan2(doublereal, doublereal), cos(doublereal), 
    sin(doublereal);
integer s_wsle(cilist *), do_lio(integer *, integer *, char *, ftnlen), 
    e_wsle(void);

/* Local variables */
static doublereal a, c__, l, m, r__, e0, u0, u1, w0, x0, x1, z0, z1, x2, 
    z2, w1, u2, w2, t2;
static integer ii;
static doublereal en[500000], pi;
static integer it;
static doublereal ts, total_time__, vel;
extern doublereal ran0_(integer *);
static doublereal enke[500000];
static integer bhit;
static doublereal enpe[500000];
static integer idum, iter, itmin;
static doublereal ttemp, xtemp, ztemp, tstep;
static integer total_itcount__;
static doublereal maxvel, tanglec, tanglei, tangler;
static integer t_write__;

/* Fortran I/O blocks */
static cilist io___43 = { 0, 6, 0, 0, 0 };
static cilist io___44 = { 0, 18, 0, 0, 0 };


o__1.oerr = 0;
o__1.ounit = 18;
o__1.ofnmlen = 24;
o__1.ofnm = "data/sinai_static_r7.txt";
o__1.orl = 0;
o__1.osta = "unknown";
o__1.oacc = 0;
o__1.ofm = 0;
o__1.oblnk = 0;
f_open(&o__1);
pi = 3.14159265358979f;
idum = 120;
/* cc      POLYGON PARAMETERS */
    r__ = .7f;
    l = 4.f;
/* cc      INITIAL CONDITIONS */
    x0 = .3f;
    z0 = .33f;
    u0 = 100.f / sqrt(2.f);
    w0 = u0 * .1f;
/* Computing 2nd power */
    d__1 = u0;
/* Computing 2nd power */
    d__2 = w0;
    e0 = d__1 * d__1 + d__2 * d__2;
/*         write(*,*) "r=",r */

/*         write(*,*) "L=",L */
    tstep = l * .5f / u0;
    itmin = 500000;
    total_itcount__ = 0;
    for (iter = 1; iter <= 500000; ++iter) {
        en[499999] = 0.f;
        enke[499999] = 0.f;
        enpe[499999] = 0.f;
    }
    for (ii = 1; ii <= 1000; ++ii) {
/*            z0=0.3*(1.0+PI*(iI-1)/NI) */
    x0 = ran0_(&idum);
    if (x0 < .5f) {
        x0 = -(r__ + x0 * 2.f * (l - r__));
    } else {
        x0 = r__ + x0 * 2.f * (l - r__);
    }
    z0 = ran0_(&idum);
    if (z0 < .5f) {
        z0 = -(r__ + z0 * 2.f * (l - r__ - a));
    } else {
        z0 = r__ + z0 * 2.f * (l - r__);
    }
/*            write(*,*) iI,x0,z0 */
    x2 = x0;
    z2 = z0;
    u2 = u0;
    w2 = w0;
/* Computing 2nd power */
    d__1 = u2;
/* Computing 2nd power */
    d__2 = w2;
    vel = sqrt(d__1 * d__1 + d__2 * d__2);
    bhit = 0;
    total_time__ = 0.f;
    maxvel = 0.f;
    it = 0;
    t_write__ = 0;
    for (iter = 1; iter <= 500000; ++iter) {
/*            if((mod(iter,100000)).eq.0.0) write(*,*) iter */
        x1 = x2;
        z1 = z2;
        u1 = u2;
        w1 = w2;
        ts = -x1 / u1;
        m = w1 / u1;
        c__ = z1 + w1 * ts;
        if (u1 > 0.f) {
/* Computing 2nd power */
        d__1 = r__;
/* Computing 2nd power */
        d__2 = m;
/* Computing 2nd power */
        d__3 = c__;
/* Computing 2nd power */
        d__4 = m;
        x2 = (-m * c__ - sqrt(d__1 * d__1 * (d__2 * d__2 + 1) - d__3 *
             d__3)) / (d__4 * d__4 + 1);
        } else {
/* Computing 2nd power */
        d__1 = r__;
/* Computing 2nd power */
        d__2 = m;
/* Computing 2nd power */
        d__3 = c__;
/* Computing 2nd power */
        d__4 = m;
        x2 = (-m * c__ + sqrt(d__1 * d__1 * (d__2 * d__2 + 1) - d__3 *
             d__3)) / (d__4 * d__4 + 1);
        }
        t2 = (x2 - x1) / u1;
        if (t2 > 0.f) {
        bhit = 3;
        } else {
        if (u1 > 0.f) {
            ttemp = (l - x1) / u1;
        } else {
            ttemp = (-l - x1) / u1;
        }
        xtemp = x1 + ttemp * u1;
        ztemp = z1 + ttemp * w1;
        t2 = 0.f;
        if (ztemp < -l) {
            t2 = (-l - z1) / w1;
            bhit = 0;
        } else if (ztemp > l) {
            t2 = (l - z1) / w1;
            bhit = 2;
        } else {
            t2 = ttemp;
            bhit = 1;
        }
        }
        x2 = x1 + t2 * u1;
        z2 = z1 + t2 * w1;
        total_time__ += t2;
        if (bhit == 0) {
        u2 = u1;
        w2 = -w1;
        } else if (bhit == 1) {
        u2 = -u1;
        w2 = w1;
        } else if (bhit == 2) {
        u2 = u1;
        w2 = -w1;
        } else if (bhit == 3) {
        tanglec = atan2(z2, x2);
        tanglei = atan2(w1, u1);
        tangler = pi + tanglec * 2.f - tanglei;
    /* Computing 2nd power */
            d__1 = u1;
    /* Computing 2nd power */
            d__2 = w1;
            vel = sqrt(d__1 * d__1 + d__2 * d__2);
            u2 = cos(tangler) * vel;
            w2 = sin(tangler) * vel;
            }
    /*               if(total_time.gt.(iT*tstep)) then */
            ++it;
    /* Computing 2nd power */
            d__1 = u2;
    /* Computing 2nd power */
            d__2 = w2;
            en[it - 1] = en[it - 1] + d__1 * d__1 + d__2 * d__2;
    /* Computing 2nd power */
            d__1 = w2;
            enke[it - 1] += d__1 * d__1;
    /* Computing 2nd power */
            d__1 = u2;
            enpe[it - 1] += d__1 * d__1;
    /*               endif */
    /*               write(18,*) iter,x2,z2,u2,w2 */
        }
    /*            write(18,*) '' */
        if (itmin > it) {
            itmin = it;
        }
        if (ii % 100 == 0) {

        s_wsle(&io___43);
        do_lio(&c__3, &c__1, (char *)&ii, (ftnlen)sizeof(integer));
        do_lio(&c__5, &c__1, (char *)&total_time__, (ftnlen)sizeof(
            doublereal));
        do_lio(&c__3, &c__1, (char *)&iter, (ftnlen)sizeof(integer));
        do_lio(&c__5, &c__1, (char *)&u2, (ftnlen)sizeof(doublereal));
        do_lio(&c__5, &c__1, (char *)&w2, (ftnlen)sizeof(doublereal));
        e_wsle();
    }
    }
    i__1 = itmin;
    for (iter = 1; iter <= i__1; ++iter) {
    s_wsle(&io___44);
    do_lio(&c__3, &c__1, (char *)&iter, (ftnlen)sizeof(integer));
    d__1 = iter * tstep;
    do_lio(&c__5, &c__1, (char *)&d__1, (ftnlen)sizeof(doublereal));
    d__2 = en[iter - 1] / 1000;
    do_lio(&c__5, &c__1, (char *)&d__2, (ftnlen)sizeof(doublereal));
    d__3 = enke[iter - 1] / 1000;
    do_lio(&c__5, &c__1, (char *)&d__3, (ftnlen)sizeof(doublereal));
    d__4 = enpe[iter - 1] / 1000;
    do_lio(&c__5, &c__1, (char *)&d__4, (ftnlen)sizeof(doublereal));
    e_wsle();
    }
    return 0;
} /* MAIN__ */

/* Main program alias */ int main_ () { MAIN__ (); return 0; }
```

Comment: This code was auto-generated by f2c. I don't have any idea about it

Comment: I changed it but increased error count

Comment: Linking with `-lm` may eliminate some of the errors.

Comment: error : 
/tmp/ccb6BLj8.o: In function `main':
sinai_static.c:(.text+0xae3): undefined reference to `MAIN'

Comment: I have no experience in Fortran. I code in java and python. Someone told me to convert this code as he doesn't know how this code is working.

Comment: You should try getting this process working with a trivial test Fortran program, then use that process on your actual code.

Comment: Yes I changed it

Comment: @tadman made a good proposal. Find a fortran HelloWorld. Try it first on that. If you succeed return to this code.

Comment: This is a link error.  I think appending `-lf2c -lm` to your link command line will address almost all of the missing symbols.  (If I remember correctly, it is actually not correct to write your own `main` in this case; libf2c provides a `main` which must be used.)

Comment: How to append this link command?

Comment: @ShubhamAttri I can't tell you how to do that because you haven't showed us exactly what you did that provoked this error.  (From the fact that you asked me this at all, I deduce that you are not simply typing compilation commands.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that f2c, at the beginning of the translated file, usually generates the following header (file name and f2c version number may be different):

```
/* helloworld.f -- translated by f2c (version 20160102).
   You must link the resulting object file with libf2c:
        on Microsoft Windows system, link with libf2c.lib;
        on Linux or Unix systems, link with .../path/to/libf2c.a -lm
        or, if you install libf2c.a in a standard place, with -lf2c -lm
        -- in that order, at the end of the command line, as in
                cc *.o -lf2c -lm
        Source for libf2c is in /netlib/f2c/libf2c.zip, e.g.,

                http://www.netlib.org/f2c/libf2c.zip
*/
```

Please follow these instructions (which coincide with @zwol advice) in order to correctly compile and link your source code.

- You need to link against the f2c library (`-lf2c` or `libf2c.a`) because it provides functions such as `f_open`, `do_lio`, `e_wsle` or `s_wsle` that are used by code generated by f2c.
- You need to link against the C math library (`-lm`) because it provides the mathematical functions used by your code (`sqrt`, `sin`, `cos`, and `atan2`).

In addition to this, you will also need to compile the other source file, `ran0.f`, and link against it.

If you are using GCC, as it seems from the form of the errors you report, the steps to follow are:

1. Compile the Fortran file `ran0.f` with the Fortran compiler

   ```
   $ gfortran ran0.f -c -o ran0.o
   ```
2. Compile the file whose source code you provided; assuming its name is `foo.c`,

   ```
   $ gcc foo.c -c -o foo.o
   ```
3. Create the binary (`foo`) by linking against the f2c library; assuming it's installed in a standard location in your operating system,

   ```
   $ gcc foo.o ran0.o -lf2c -lm -o foo
   ```

   Otherwise, you have to find where the file `libf2c.a` is located in your system (e.g., `/home/myuser/code/f2c/lib/libf2c.a`) and use that path in the linking command, instead of `-lf2c`:

   ```
   $ gcc foo.o ran0.o /home/myuser/code/f2c/lib/libf2c.a -lm -o foo
   ```

If you want to also convert file `ran0.f` to C, instead of step 1. above you should first use `f2c` to convert the Fortran source file `ran0.f`to a C source file

```
$ f2c ran0.f
```

(this creates file `ran0.c`) and then compile the C source file to create the object file `ran0.o`

```
$ gcc ran0.c -c -o ran0.o
```

Then proceed with steps 2. and 3. as above.

Comment: If the answer helped you to solve your problem, you can mark it as "the accepted answer" so you make it easier to other people with the same question to easily discover the solution.