# building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64

Tags: c, xcode, f2c

What I am trying to accomplish is to take code generated from `f2c` and use it in my existing Xcode project. I have all of the `.C` files in my project directory but I am unable to build the project. I [asked a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369961/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-building-c-files-in-xcode) but I think what I am now experiencing is a separate issue so I am asking a new question.

I know that there is a `libf2c.a` file that is also a part of using `f2c` and I suspect it was part of the issue with my original question I asked but I am unsure. I tried placing the `libf2c.a` file in my Xcode project and including it in Targets->Build phases->Link binary with libraries and added the path to Build Settings->Search Paths->Library search paths but I still was getting the same error as in my other question which was:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
      "_s_wsle", referenced from:
          _xplannr_ in X1.o

          ...
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now after doing some more research I discovered that a `.a` file is just an archive and everything can be extracted with `ar x libf2c.a` and that is what I did. After running that command I got a bunch of `.o` files. I placed all of the `.o` files in my Xcode project and now the error I get for almost every `.o` file is:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../libf2c.a, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../wsne.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../getenv_.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../s_cmp.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../c_abs.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../h_mod.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../wsfe.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../sfe.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_abs.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../ctype.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_log.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../main.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_sin.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../hl_lt.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_lg10.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_sinh.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../err.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../i_dim.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../dolio.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_imag.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_sin.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_exp.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../f77vers.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../etime_.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../i_indx.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../lbitbits.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_sqrt.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../z_log.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_nint.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_cos.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../signal_.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../l_lt.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../ftell_.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../uio.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../i_len.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../cabs.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_sign.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../h_nint.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../sue.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../c_exp.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_dim.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../z_sqrt.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../util.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_cnjg.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_abs.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_cosh.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../s_stop.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../exit_.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../typesize.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../z_exp.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_tan.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_imag.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../rsfe.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../pow_ii.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../h_dim.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../c_sqrt.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../pow_ci.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../rsli.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../s_paus.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../c_sin.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../c_log.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../getarg_.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../h_len.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../hl_gt.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../wsle.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../i_mod.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../fmtlib.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../ilnw.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_tan.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../c_cos.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../pow_zi.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../pow_di.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_mod.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../lwrite.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../ef1cmc_.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_acos.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_sign.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../open.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_atn2.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../derfc_.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../pow_dd.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../lread.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../h_abs.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_int.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_dim.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_asin.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../r_int.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../fmt.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../d_atan.o, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting ...

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_s_wsle", referenced from:
      _plannr_ in X1.o
  ...
```

I see there is a `wsle.o` file so I would imagine `_s_wsle` would come from there as one example?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50887659/1489990) seems to solve the problem in general but I think I need some help doing the same thing within Xcode.

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You have a library built for Intel/AMD instruction set which resists being linked with code written for ARM.  Best would be to get the version of the library compiled for ARM64.

Comment: @stark Yes so I think I understand that now. Previously I was compiling the library on an intel mac and I compiled it again on an M1 mac (which I would think is ARM64) but xcode gives `building for iOS, but linking in object file built for macOS` with the new files I have compiled. So was that not the right idea or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Not too familiar with MAC but I believe it supports emulated x86 instructions.  However a single app needs to be all x86 or all ARM.